# Trying to call C# code with a JavaScript button on a WebView

Tags: javascript, c#, web, xamarin.forms, maps

Note that I'm specifically talking about calling C# after clicking on a Javascript button that is inside my webview, in this case a `HybridWebView`.

I followed a lot of tips and ideas I seen around like the samples provided by [XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) and the documentation about `HybridWebViews` in the Xamarin.Forms guides.

I have the following structure:

`Hybridwebview` Class with the methods to `RegisterAction` and `InvokeAction`;

`Page` that uses my `HybridWebView`;

A custom renderer in each of my platforms that are injecting the Javascript I want in the webview.

I believe the problem is in the `InjectJS` method that I have in my renderer. It is using `LoadUrl` to inject javascript in the `WebView` and that is "deleting" my `WebView` and replacing it with the button that has the Javascript function.

This is the code of my renderer for Android!
[image: This is the code of my renderer for Android]

On the left is the result that this creates and on the right the result I was expecting
[image: On the left is the result that this creates and on the right the result I was expecting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the `div` I created started without defined values for width and height and because of that the content was being displayed has hidden.

Fixed after adding `Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);` and then debugging on the device and google chrome tools

Comment: Saved me.  Thanks for posting. The stock HybridWebView sample at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/  had this issue.  if I ran to emulator it ran fine, if it ran to a physical device nothing would show up.  Changing 
    <p id="result">Result: </p> 
    <div id="result" style="height:400px;width:400px;">Result:</div>

Answer (score 1):

Setting height and width on a the result saved me.

The stock HybridWebView sample at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/  had the "no show" issue.

If I ran to emulator it ran fine.

If it ran to a physical device nothing would show up.  Changing index.html

```
<p id="result">Result: </p>
```

to

```
<div id="result" style="height:400px;width:400px;">Result:</div>
```

made the output show up.